# Disable GUI for reminding of updates in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

So unattended updates are configured to run at every shutdown, OK.

But until that point, a GUI comes up on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop saying that XY needs to be upgraded.

**The big Question:** How can we disable the GUI pop-up Window to the users?

Answer (score 0):

Open Synaptic Package Manager then go to Settings -> Repositories -> Updates and uncheck *Check for updates*.

I'm not sure how you have unattended updates set up, but if it's using a cron job then this should work fine.